# Updating Item info in "Link to Documents" content type whenever a document is updated

Tags: document

Need your help!
I have a site collection. Have one common library where all documents are hosted(with fields: Document name, Version No., Version Comments).
There are several sub sites with a library in each, which will have links to these documents.(custom content type used)
Problem is that whenever a document is updated in common library, the updated fields(Version No., Version Comments etc) are not updated in respective sub sites where link to documents content type is used.
I want the updated version(fields) should appear in links also, whenever the same is updated for any document in the common library.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Is it possible to handle this scenario with event handlers? If yes, can you please share the code?